# Proving that $\sup f'\left( \left( 0,\infty \right) \right)=0$ under a certain set of conditions.

Tags: derivatives, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $\left( 0,\infty  \right)$ s.t. $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in \left( 0,\infty  \right)$. Prove, that if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $\underset{x\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,f\left( x \right)=L<\infty $.
2. $\forall x\in \left( 0,\infty  \right).f'\left( x \right)<0$.

Then $\sup f'\left( \left( 0,\infty  \right) \right)=0$ .

How would you go about proving this?

Comment: the idea should be something like: if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$, exists, then f should be flat at infinity. Maybe you could check how the difference $f(x+1)-f(x)$ behaves as $x$ is large. Using the MVT/Taylor might give some useful insights there. Note that $sup f'\leq 0$ is clear. The only thing that remains is equality. To this end you need to check large $x$ values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not need the existence of or condition fulfilled by $f''$.

Since $f'(x)<0$, certainly $\sup f'\le 0$. Assume $\sup f'=s<0$. Then $f'(x)\le s$ for all $x$. Consequently, $f(x)\le f(1)+(x-1)s$ for all $x>1$ (MVT). For $x$ big enough, this is $<L-1$, contradicting $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$.

Comment: Hi Hagen von Eitzen. Thanks very much for your quick response and elegant solution. Much obliged!